# Drag and Drop files from browser to LibreOffice Writer not working

Tags: unity, launcher, libreoffice, drag-and-drop

I tried to drag and drop an image on unity bar hoping that it will bring LibreOffice Writer in focus but it didn't not.

So now i have to goto insert ---> pictures

*How to solve this issue.*

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, right click on the image and select "Copy Image." Then in LibreOffice, paste the image using "Edit --> Paste" or Control+V.

Comment: But not all images show the option of Copy Image thats the problemo

Comment: are you trying to copy from a browser?

Comment: Ya I do. Look in windows and other Linux Distros, When u try to drag and drop any image it immediately copied on destination, So im doing the same in unity but it doesnot work. U try the same and u will know

Comment: If you can't copy in your browser (what browser?), then right click and save the image to your desktop. Then, with the mouse drag the image into your LO file.